# No third party apps (GoToMeeting, Google Hangouts, etc) can use my Microphone

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, microphone

Windows 8.1 on an HP laptop.  Within Windows itself, my microphone works just fine.   I can go to Sound > Recording, and the Microphone is clearly picking up noise.

[image]

However, on a regular basis, I have meetings with remote co-workers using GoToMeeting, Google Hangouts and Google Meet.  And in all three of them, they can't hear me. This started just yesterday. Before that, everything worked fine. I've checked, and there have been no Windows Updates for several weeks.

If I use an external audio source like a set of USB headphones then it works fine.  But I don't always have a set handy.  There is something going on with the default microphone that it doesn't seem to want to share audio with third party apps.

I've gone through the troubleshooting steps suggested by the tools I listed above, and they have been no help.  They are very basic:  Make sure your Mic is not muted. Reboot, etc.

I'm at a loss here.  What else should I be looking for?

Comment: You could maybe rollback to a system restore point before yesterday.

Comment: last case option!

Comment: Did you run the Windows Troubleshooting for audio?

Comment: Yes.  It said it didn't find any problems.

Comment: Has Windows Update installed something yesterday? Look in Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update > View update history.

Comment: Hey @harrymc, this was in my OP: "I've checked, and there have been no Windows Updates for several weeks."

Comment: Right, missed that. Another try : uninstall/reinstall one of the problematic products.

Comment: What about deleting the audio device, downloading latest drivers and installing those?

Comment: I don't know the tools you mentioned, however all the tools I know (bt meetme, zoom, skype for business)  has an option to test your devices without joining any meeting. I suppose your tools can do that too, have you tried it? That could help to get closer to the issue.